# Passing arrays as function arguments

Tags: go

I expected the following code snippet either to produce `a` as `{0x01, 0x02}` (pass by value) or as `{0x03, 0x02, 0x01}` (pass by reference). Strangely, it produces the output as `{0x03, 0x02}`. Could you please help me understand why is that?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func test1(t []byte) {
    t[0] = 0x03
    t = append(t, 0x01 )
}

func main() {
    a := []byte{0x01, 0x02 }
    test1(a)
    _ = a
    fmt.Printf("%v", a)
}
```

Comment: is it related to https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_4. ?

Comment: Please forget the whole notion of "pass by reference" when thinking about Go: It is not helpful and never correct. Everything is always passed by value in Go. Some values like slices do not "own" all data accessible through it. Slice values are such values: A slice does not own its elements. The slice is passed by value, the elements are not passed at all. See: No pass by reference anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go `[]byte` is not an array, it's a byte slice.

What happened is that the size of `a` was 2, and because of that, after its first element was changed to 3, `append` allocated a new bigger slice - and `t` was set to the address of the new slice that was allocated, but that doesn't affect the `a` in `main`.

From [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) about `append`:

> If the backing array of s is too small to fit all the given values a bigger array will be allocated. The returned slice will point to the newly allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

The slice header is passed by value, but it references the same backing array. So when you change the first value it is changed in the original array as well. When you call `append` a new slice header is generated and written to the space occupied by the original argument value thus staying local to the method.